# If $f$ is Riemann integrable and $f>0$ for $x\in[a,b]$ then $\int{f>0}$

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

I've seen the proof and it seems much less trivial than what I had in mind. 
Can anyone point out to me what is wrong about the following proof:

Let P be some partition of $[a,b]$ such that: 
$$ P= \begin{Bmatrix} a = x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < · · · < x_{n−1} < x_n = b \end{Bmatrix}$$

$$\forall  x\in[a,b]: f(x)>0 \Rightarrow 0<\min_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)\Longrightarrow 0<\sum_{i=1}^{n} \min_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}{f(x)} \cdot \Delta x_{i}$$
let $L(f, P)$ be the lower sum of partition P

$$0<\sum_{i=1}^{n} \min_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}{f(x)} \cdot \Delta x_{i}=L(f,P)\le\sup_{P}{L(f,P')}=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx $$

hence
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx > 0$$

Comment: You do not know if $f$ actually attains its minimum on any interval

Comment: It might be easier to show that if $f \ge 0$ and $\int f = 0$ then $f = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Those conditions would imply that $f = 0$ a.e., not necessarily everywhere. But is this possible to prove without any Lebesgue machinery?

Comment: @copper.hat I guess this [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/351196/169852) of yours addresses that - you don't need the full notion of Lebesgue measure or Lebesgue integration, but you do need the notions of measure zero and content zero.

Comment: Alternatively, it suffices to show that a Riemann integrable function is continuous somewhere. In fact, it must have [infinitely many points of continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776398/a-riemann-integrable-function-must-have-infinitely-many-points-of-continuity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear: **the statement is correct,but the proof you are demonstrating is not**. There is a very, very slight point that contains a mistake. You are saying that since $f(x)>0$ for all $x$, it is $\min_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)>0$. Why do you think this minimum exists? If it is a minimum, then fine, it will be equal to $f(\xi_i)$ for some $\xi_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$ therefore strictly positive. But this is not always the case! The following two examples **illustrate why this is not always the case**:

For example: There is a famous theorem that says $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the discontinuities of $f$ form a set of measure zero. Now we can have sets of measure zero that are very, very weird. For example the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). Denote by $C$ the classic cantor set and define a function $f:[0,1]\to(0,\infty)$ by $f(x)=1$ if $x\not\in C$ and we define $f$ however we want on $C$, but it must be strictly positive. We can define $f$ to be positive and satisfying for any $\delta>0$

$$\inf_{x\in[1/3-\delta,1/3+\delta]}f(x)=0$$
(Look at the wikipedia link to visualize the Cantor set. Can you think of a way to define such an $f$? remember, you can define $f(x)$ **however you like** on $C$ and you will still get a Riemann integrable function. The only restriction is that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$)

This function provides a counter example, since if we partition $[0,1]$ in subintervals, $1/3$ has to belong to a subinterval, therefore the infimum of $f$ in this subinterval will be $0$.

**Edit**: a **much** simpler counter example: set $f(x)=1$ everywhere on $[0,1]$ except  $\{0.5+1/n: n\geq3\}$. For these points, set $f(0.5+1/n)=1/n$. Then the same thing happens at $0.5$ (and of course $f$ is positive, Riemann integrable).

Comment: Does your counter example mean that: if $f>0$ then not always $\int{f}$>0?
(for a Riemann integrable function)

Comment: @henshar No! It is indeed true that if $f>0$ then it is $\int f>0$, but the proof you are presenting here has an error. My counter-examples simply point out that error.

Comment: I think it would help to clarify what your counterexample is a counterexample to. A casual reader would incorrectly presume that is is a counterexample to the question.

Comment: @copper.hat sure, I'll edit.